# Parsing CSV by column in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

Given a CSV file with some data arranged in columns instead of rows:

```
Parameters;Data Set 1;Data Set 2
param_1;A;1
param_2;B;2
param_3;C;3
param_4;D;4
param_5;E;5
```

Is it possible to use this as a "CSV config element" in JMeter? For sure it won't work with the standard config elements but maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 2):

CSV config element cannot do this. You should use a BeanShell Sampler or JSR223 Sampler to read the file and process each line. Here is a simple Java code for BeanShell sampler:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
String line = br.readLine();
while (!line.isEmpty()) { 
    String parts = line.split(";");
    String paramName = parts[0];
    String dataSet1 = parts[1];
    String dataSet2 = parts[2];
    // save them in jmeter props or vars and use later
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `CSV Data Set Config` write the names of the parameters in `Variable Names(comma-delimited)` with `,` separation. (like `Parameters,DataSet1,DataSet2`).

Set the `Loop Count` for the `Thread Group` as the number of lines you have to read.

Now you will get the values by accessing the variables `${Parameters}, ${DataSet1}, ${DataSet2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "CSV config element", use "User Parameters" pre-processor, it will work as you expected. But you need to add values manually.